# How to implement Google App Engine on an existing Symfony project?

Tags: symfony, google-app-engine

I want to enable Google App Engine support for my Symfony2 application. The problem is, I have no idea on how to do this on an existing app - I've found this:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-symfony-starter-project

But this requires me to create a fresh, new project, and I just want to enable this on my existing app. How to achieve such thing?

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the [app.yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-symfony-starter-project/blob/master/app.yaml) and [php.ini](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-symfony-starter-project/blob/master/php.ini) from the `appengine-symfony-starter-project` to the root of your project. Next, add the methods in [AppKernel.php](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-symfony-starter-project/blob/master/app/AppKernel.php) into your existing AppKernel class.

Finally, copy over `data` and `Environment.php` in the [src](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-symfony-starter-project/tree/master/src/AppEngine) directory to the `src` directory of your project.

This should get you started. Because AppEngine is a sandbox environment, you may still run into some errors from incompatible functions. See [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/runtime) for more information about the configuration of AppEngine's PHP Runtime.

Good luck! And if you run into issues, please post them [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-symfony-starter-project/issues)